# docker compose network_mode: "host" not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My dockerized app needs to access something on the localhost network which is not possible without `network_mode: "host"`

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    network_mode: "host"
    image: node:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
      - node_modules:/usr/app/node_modules
    working_dir: /usr/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

volumes: 
  node_modules:
```

If I comment out `network_mode: "host"` my app works perfectly on http://localhost:3000. If I re-add it it stills runs but no longer accessible on http://localhost:3000.

Edit: I just tested a hello world on Ubuntu and it works, but not on mac, mac doesm't seem to work with `network_mode: "host"`

Comment: localhost:3000 still 404

Comment: are you accessing the URL from same machine or differnt?

Comment: same machine, on my local mac. I know the port 3000 is listening inside docker because I can curl from docker exec, but not from outside docker

Comment: add the output for docker-composw ps

Comment: no dockerfile inside repo.Without docker file  context: . this is of no use

Comment: I'm using an image, not a docker file, there is no docker file. I don't know what build is, you told me to add it.

Comment: Why are you using Docker here?  Can you just use your host’s installed `node` instead, and avoid this problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze why wouldn't I use docker? node is annoying to install and has many different versions, platforms and incompatibility issues.

Comment: @Dave Have you deleted the repo. I was tryin to check your issue
?

Comment: What version of docker on Mac? Is that docker-machine and does `echo $DOCKER_HOST` output anything?

Comment: @BMitch Version 2.0.0.2 (30215), it does not echo anything

Answer (score 35):

yes at the moment of writing this, there is definitely an issue with **mac**, the issues is that docker in **mac** uses a linux virtual machine where containers live, so when you use `network_mode: "host"` it will only be valid for the VM's network, not for your mac :(  more info [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3800).

As an alternative, do not use `network_mode: "host"`, instead keep it in bridge (the default) then configure your service to instead of reaching **localhost:xxxx**, use **host.docker.internal:xxxx**

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct

Comment: please do mark this answer as correct! 100%

Comment: I spent 4 hours debugging this. My code works in linux, but cant connect in mac.

Comment: at the moment of writing this, this network_mode issue with mac still exists

Comment: confirmed, still have this issue